# Where Can I Find the Old Wifi Drivers?

Tags: iwlwifi

Something happened and I have to load another ubuntu onto my computer. So I'm using the alternate installer for 12.04LTS (the same as before) but unfortuantely, I don't have the wifi driver I need.. the only one my wifi card will take is the:

```
iwlwifi-7260-6.ucode
```

THE 6, not the 7 or 8 which is currently offered.. the six works, both the others don't even they're newer.. The Card I have is the **Intel Wireless 7260 AC** The install disk won't even take the others..

Anyone know where I can get this?

I wrote on this subject in a past Ask Ubuntu and this is what I figured out which works, unfortunately it worked and stopped working after I played with the "Advanced Settings" App to try to permanently get rid of the BlueTooth program running on Ubuntu which I didn't want cause I don't seem to have any BlueTooth Devices

Comment: What version of Ubuntu did it work in before?

Comment: 12.04.3LTS.. Same one as now I'm trying

Comment: You don't happen to know what kernel version you used in that other install do you?

Comment: no, but I'm downloading a new alternate installer just in case this is the problem.. hopefully this'll do it.. strangely enough, the Intel Linux drivers web page has their firmware listed as 3160.ucode for the card

Comment: Alright. It would also be useful to know what kernel version you are trying to use now.

Comment: how do I find that out?

Comment: Use `uname -a` in a terminal

Comment: ok, it's 3.8.0-29 Generic. And it's still asking for the number 6..

Comment: I'm running the (what I assume is) the latest alternate installer with the latest colnel..

Comment: What do you mean it's "asking"? Is it actually asking something?

Comment: yes, it actually says: "The missing firmware files are: islwifi-7260-6.ucode . And it won't take anything else. I even tried changing the file name and nothing. This file has to be somewhere out there??

Comment: You should be able to download the firmware from [here](http://wireless.kernel.org/en/users/Drivers/iwlwifi), but since I've never used the alternative installer I'm not sure what you'll have to do after you download it... Try downloading the latest version with the command `wget http://wireless.kernel.org/en/users/Drivers/iwlwifi?action=AttachFile&do=get&target=iwlwifi-7260-ucode-22.15.8.0.tgz`

Comment: Or, if you install 13.10 or 14.04 (which will be released in April) it should work out of the box.

Comment: yeah, I tried those.. They don't work, they want the 6 and the 6 only!! This really burns me, why couldn't they just leave it up there, now I can't use my wifi because of them!!!

Comment: I have been unable to find a 6 version.. I'll resume my search later (dinner now), but in the meantime try the 13.10 and 14.04 alternate installers. Do either of those work?

Comment: the other distros were much more problematic then 12.04 which is why I chose 12.04.. I used the Alternate Installer cause I wanted the stability (or at least what I can do for it and none of the others) that 12.04 offered and the full disk encryption which only the alternate installer could do for it. And the others don't have alternate installers.. :(